# neural network using R (neural net package)

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to forecast sales of retail companies. 
I am using the neural net package neural net.

My code:

```
    nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train_,hidden=c(14,12,4),linear.output=F,threshold = 0.01,
        stepmax = 1e+08, rep = 10, startweights = NULL,learningrate.limit = NULL,
        learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.6, plus = 1.15),
        learningrate=NULL, lifesign = "none",
    algorithm = "rprop+", err.fct = "sse", act.fct = "logistic", 
exclude = NULL,constant.weights = NULL, likelihood = FALSE)
```

My model is not even as good as a linear regression. 
What can I do to improve accuracy of the model ??

Data: 2'300 Quaters (for e.g. Q1 2003) and 18 variables (for e.g. inventories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the specifics of this package, but I did some meddling with neural nets using keras.

From what I understand from the function parameters you are using a default learning rate, how about trying to set one? I would vary it between 0.01 and 0.0001 and check the results.

Also, did you try a different activation function, such as one linear?

Finally, how did you choose the number of layers? Since this is a regression problem I guess you are not limited to 4 nodes on your output layer. I would loop over a few variations and check results.

I'm not very experienced in Neural Networks though, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I will try the changes and see if it improves the accuracy!

Comment: the smaller the learning rate the more accurate your model will be. It will just take longer the smaller your learning rate becomes.

Comment: do you mean I should use for e.g. learningrate.factor = list (minus=0.99, plus=1.01) ? @nak5120